# Send a tweet from an iPhone app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, oauth, twitter, tweets

What is the best way to tweet from an iPhone app?

I know there are some libraries to integrate twitter in an iPhone app like MGTwitterEngine, do I really need it just to sent a tweet?
And what is OAuth? is MGTwitterEngine already include OAuth??
Can someone tell me what are the steps I need to do from start?

The app is for ios 4, so using the new twitter framework in ios 5 is not good for me..

Comment: MGTwitterEngine has so many issues. I would suggest you may go for Twitter framework by Apple.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using iOS 5 there is a whole Twitter Framework built in. Otherwise you will have to use a third party library to do this.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Twitter/Reference/TwitterFrameworkReference/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011014

**UPDATE**

Please also do note that Apple will no longer accept anything that can not run on iPhone 5, so you will have to be use iOS 6 SDK or later anyway